# How can a Urdu date printer in twig using Drupal 8

Tags: date, drupal, twig, urdu

I am working on printing date in more than one language in the English language. No problem but I have a problem of course, Date in Urdu,
In **Drupal 7** I used **PHP** this way

```
<span class="arabic-date">  <?php
$arrayurdudays = array('', 'پير', 'منگل', 'بدھ', 'جمعرات', 'جمعه', 'ہفتہ', 'اتوار');
print  format_date(time(), 'custom', ' l ، d F ، Y', null, 'ur'); ?></span>
```

But now with **Drupal 8** using **[twig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNCbJ.png)** I tried more than one way and it didn't work for me,

I downloaded model (Configuration Translation) that did not work for me,

I have read that there is a way to print it inside a file (**.theme**), but I did not understand the method well,

Because I need it inside the header file.

[In Drupal 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBIJo.png)

[Figure previously in Drupal 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37owj.png)

Comment: It's okay that you say: "it doesn't work". But what does not work? Perhaps it just an encoding issue...

Comment: I tried coding inside Drupal (l, F  j, Y), translating it and printing it inside the header, but it doesn't take it

Comment: But there is some output? Or is it ignored?

Comment: Outputs appear correctly, but they are in English not Urdu

Comment: look at the pictures